# How to display unreachable commits using `git log`?

Tags: git

I make use of the following `git` command to display the commit history below:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all -n 25
```

I want to display the (unreachable) commit `490ab89` as part of the history after resetting to the root commit `20513d9`:

```
*   490ab89 (HEAD -> feature) Merge branch 'feature2' into feature
|\
| * a47187b (feature2) Adds random-file
* | b39cb83 (master) Adds some-file
|/
* 20513d9 Adds hello-world

git reset --hard 20513d9

* a47187b (feature2) Adds random-file
| * b39cb83 (master) Adds some-file
|/
* 20513d9 (HEAD -> feature) Adds hello-world
```

How can I make `git log` display unreachable commits?

Comment: If you would have done a `--soft` reset, git would have been to reach that.
Since it was a `--hard` reset, git has not kept the record of those commits. At least not using git log. 
You might want to use git reflog to restore head to 490ab89 and then trying git log

Comment: @UtsavPatel: that's entirely wrong: a `--soft` reset still moves the branch name, in this case `feature`, to the selected commit. It just leaves the index and work-tree untouched, enabling easy re-committing of the snapshot that's currently in the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give `git log` a raw commit hash ID, if you remember it:

```
git log 490ab89
```

or, with your options:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all -n 25 490ab89
```

Note that the `-n 25` limit could conceivably hide `490ab89` if 25 other commits get displayed first.  When `git log` has more than one commit to visit at a time—as it does with `--all 490ab89` since the names `feature`, `feature2`, and `master` select three other commits, giving a total of 4 to visit initially—it places the commit hash IDs into a priority queue.  It then takes one commit from the priority queue, displays it, and inserts its parent(s) into the queue.  Commit `490ab89` will be visited only once it reaches the front of the queue, which obviously depends on its priority relative to other commits.

(The default priority order is by committer timestamp, with later commits—those with higher timestamps—having greater priority.  The `--graph` option implies the `--topo-order` option, which alters these priorities somewhat.)

Assuming you have reflogs enabled, you can also use the reflog entries to locate the appropriate hash ID.  In this case both `HEAD@{1}` and `feature@{1}` would name commit `490ab89`.

Comment: Thank you. In other words, there is no option for `git log`, like `--show-unreachable` that would make `git` display unreachable commits? I don't think it will be feasible to remember the commit hash ID (`490ab89`) :-)

Comment: @Shuzheng The thing about a truly unreachable commit is that it is unreachable. Once a commit is unreachable, it is no concern of git's; you are lucky if it even still exists. If this commit is important to you, make it reachable by giving it a name (e.g. a branch name or a tag name). Then `--all` will include it.

Comment: Also: Git's *reflog* entries will hang on to previous values of ref (branch, tag, etc) names, but reflog entries eventually expire. That's one of the key differences between a reflog entry, and an actual name: the *name* doesn't expire on its own.